# Mongodb Group by get $max and count of max in value and percent of that group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to a group by on x field and get the max value of other fields. Yes, using `$max` we can get max repetitive value. But, I also need to get count `$max` value in percent/count too. In other words, how many times this `$max` value exist in that group. Kindly help.

example:

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate(
    [
        { "$match" : { "doc_id" : 1.0 } }, 
        { "$group" : {
                "_id" : { "name" : "$name" }, 
                "total" : { "$sum" : "$amount" }, 
                "l1_max" : { "$max" : "$l1" }
            }
        }, 
    ]
);
```

Here, I am getting `l1_max = 'Computer'` . But, I need it as `'Computer - (30%) Total 4/12'`

**Updated**: 20/10/2019
@mickl : Thanks for the answer.

The field l1 is actually a referenced field. In normal find/project or mongoose populate(), it helps to get fields from other collection. Example: 
if l1 is of type ObjectId then,

```
l1: {
_id, "4343434343sdsdsY",
name: "IT"
}
```

So l1.name will fetch name field from another collection in project/populate function.

I executed following code:

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate(
    [
        { "$match" : { "doc_id" : 1.0 } }, 
        { "$group" : {
                "_id" : { "name" : "$name" }, 
                "total" : { "$sum" : "$amount" }, 
                "count": { '$sum': 1 },
                "l1_max" : { "$max" : "$l1" },
                "l1_values": { $push: "$l1" }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                total: 1,
                l1 : {"_id": "$l1_max", "count": "$count", "percent": { $divide: [ { $size: { $filter: { input: "$l1_values", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this", "$l1_max" ] } } } },"$count"]}}
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Answer is like below: But I also need referenced **name** field too.

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "xzy"
    }, 
    "total" : 35.0, 
    "l1" : {
        "_id" : "4343920239201W", 
        "name" : "IT",                // **MISSING**
        "count" : 4.0, 
        "percent" : 0.25
    }
}
```

Hope I was clear this time.

Comment: can you add sample collection json and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture all `l1` values in your group and the calculate the percent using [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html), [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) and [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html):

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate(
    [
        { "$match" : { "doc_id" : 1.0 } }, 
        { "$group" : {
                "_id" : { "name" : "$name" }, 
                "total" : { "$sum" : "$amount" }, 
                "l1_max" : { "$max" : "$l1" },
                "l1_values": { $push: "$l1" }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                total: 1,
                l1_max: 1,
                l1_perc: { 
                    $divide: [
                        { $size: { $filter: { input: "$l1_values", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this", "$l1_max" ] } } } },
                        { $size: "$l1_values" }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bVLTr-L1lvq)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. Just to add more, the field l1 is a reference field. How to read another collection 'name' field i.e. at the end I need to get l1._id and l1.name. Currently, I am trying, this concat but its says l1 is referenced, cant concatenate .

Comment: @Vikash what you described is a bit unclear. Could you please open another question and describe your new requirements with some examples ? Thanks !

Comment: @Vikash $lookup is what you need: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/